# reading in and using a txt file java

Tags: java, file, loops, io

I'm trying to finish my lab in my intro to CS course and am having trouble reading in information from txt files and using it.

Below is my code so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class loops {
public static void main (String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException{

File myFile = new File("Snowboard_Scores.txt");
Scanner input = new Scanner(myFile);

String name;
String country;
int snow1;
int snow2;
int snow3;
double score;
int max = 0;

while (input.hasNext() ){
    System.out.println(input.nextLine());
    max++;
}
System.out.println(max);

for (int count = 0; count < max; count ++){

}
}
}
```

The lab is simple, I'm comparing three scores from 4+ different snowboarders. Each snowboarder has a name, a country and 3 scores from judges. I need to average the scores, then compare it to all the snowboarders to see who had the best score and then print that snowboarders name and country.

I'm struggling with collecting and storing all the data in a way that will be useful. WE CANNOT USE ARRAYS at this point in our labs, anybody have any ideas on how to go about this?

**Snowboard_Scores.txt:**

```
 Shaun White
 United States
 9.7
 9.8
 9.6
 Bob Saget
 Yugolsavia
 1.4
 2.1
 1.9
 Morgan Freeman
 Antartica
 10.0 
 9.9
 9.8
 Diana Natalicio    
 Brazil
 8.7
 8.7
 9.2
```

Comment: How is the file `Snowboard_Scores.txt` ?

Comment: Sorry, should have added that.
It goes line by line, 

First Line Name
Second Line Country
2-5 Line Scores
6 Line Name
7 Line Country, etc.

Comment: You said you can't use arrays. What can you use?

Comment: While Loops, For Loops, Counters. 
I apologize, this is only our 4th lab assignment so the limitations might be somewhat frustrating for more experienced programmers.

Comment: Better way is to create class snowboarder with attribute name,country and avrg score.Iterate the file and create the object and set it into the list.Then you can easily found the best score

Comment: what about just getting the average of the one read and comparing it to the one stored. Because you only need to save the highest score you can compare the one you just read to the one saved. If the one read is higher then set it, otherwise discard it.

Comment: rpax, I was thinking getting the total lines, then dividing by the amount of lines per snowboarder. Since each snowboarder has a name, country and 3 scores, they have 5 values attributed to them. IF total length is 20, if we divide 20/20 we get the name. To get name of 2nd guy, its whatever the variable for 20/20 was, plus 5. To get name of 3rd guy, its the current value, and then add another 5 again. I know it seems dumb and elementary, but thats the only thing i can think of

Comment: @OmarKhalik You are overthinking this. I think it may come from the phrasing of the question. You dont need to compare every snowboarder with every other one. Because you only need the BEST score you only need to compare each snowboarder to the last one you parsed. If Morgan Freemans score is better than Shawn White then who cares about White am I right?

Comment: I didn't think about that approach, but you're right. I didn't think to use If Else statements until much later in the code, but it makes sense to embed one inside a loop. Thanks!

Comment: But now how would I go about that? How do I grab the next 3 doubles in the code piece by piece and average them? I need to compare the average of snowboarder 1 with snowboarder 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its too simple;
process data while you read data;
read each snowboard and compare with best prev value;
then best is selected as best value; see code below

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class loops {
public static void main (String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException{

    File myFile = new File("Snowboard_Scores.txt");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(myFile);

    String name = "";
    String country = "";
    double score = 0.0;

    while (input.hasNext() ){
        String tmp_name = input.nextLine();
        String tmp_country = input.nextLine();
        double tmp = Double.parseDouble(input.nextLine())/3;
        tmp += Double.parseDouble(input.nextLine())/3;
        tmp += Double.parseDouble(input.nextLine())/3;
        if(tmp > score){
            name = tmp_name;
            country = tmp_county;
            score = tmp;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(name);
    System.out.println(country);
}
```

you right. one line **missed**

Comment: You never modify score after you have initialized it. After country = tmp_county; score = tmp; ?

Comment: This works, however the name of the country is not displayed for whatever reason.

Comment: I think your input file have empty line. check it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just a slight modification.

```
while (input.hasNext()){

 String tmp_name = input.nextLine();
 String tmp_country = input.nextLine();

 double tmp_avg = Double.parseDouble(input.nextLine())/3;
 tmp_avg += Double.parseDouble(input.nextLine())/3;
 tmp_avg += Double.parseDouble(input.nextLine())/3;

 if(tmp_avg > score){
  score = tmp_avg;
  name = tmp_name;
  country = tmp_country;
 }
}
```